# How to get value of optarg without using command line?

Tags: c++, getopt

I used ***getopt()*** function to get value of optarg parameters in Visual Studio. However, following to document of GNU, ***getopt()*** is a function that used to parse command-line options of the Unix/POSIX style and I can not use commandline in Visual Studio. So, how can I get the ***optarg*** in VS without using ***command line or getopt()***.
Here is my code:

```
    int ch;
    extern char* optarg;/*
    extern int optind, opterr;*/

    char* testfn;
    bool testflag = false;

    double prd = 60 * 24; // minutes of a day  
    int maxstep = 100; // # em steps
    int Z = 2; // # mixtures
    double initscale = 0.25 * prd; // 6 hours

    while (optind < argc) {
        if ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "t:m:z:s:")) != -1) {
            switch (ch) {
            case 't':
                testflag = true;
                testfn = optarg;
                break;
            case 'm':
                maxstep = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'z':
                Z = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 's':
                initscale = atof(optarg);
                break;
            default:
                usage();
            }
        }
        else {
            // Regular argument
            //code to handle the argument
            optind++;  // Skip to the next argument
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Project Properties -> Debugging ->Command Arguments`

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh thank you very much. When I set Command Argument equal 't' and I got argc = 2, but optarg is still Null . How can I fix it?

Comment: `optarg` is only valid when the option has an argument, and `t` expects an argument (that's why you wrote a colon after it). For instance, `-t yes`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried `-t yes` and it's so amazing. The code ran and return `optarg` value. Thank you very much <3